# I am using NEO4J apoc.refactor.setType to change the rel type of a relationship with no luck

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

```
I am trying to change the rel type of a relationship as outlined below and getting the following error:
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 4, column 22 (offset: 224))
"                     call apoc.refactor.setType(r, 'OWNED')"
```

If adding YIELD is the answer I am not sure what to YIELD ??

```
MATCH (user:Owner {email: "xyz@mymail.com"})-[r:OWNS]->(v:Vehicles {name:"Chevy"})
                         WHERE r.model = "Silverado" OR NOT EXISTS(r.model)
                         WITH r,user,v
                         call apoc.refactor.setType(r, 'OWNED')
                         YIELD ?????
                        RETURN user,r,v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [apoc.help](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/help/) procedure to see the signature of APOC functions. For example, the result of this statement:

```
CALL apoc.help("apoc.refactor.setType")
```

is:

```
╒═══════════╤══════════════════╤══════════════════╤══════════════════╤═══════╤════════╕
│"type"     │"name"            │"text"            │"signature"       │"roles"│"writes"│
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│"procedure"│"apoc.refactor.set│"apoc.refactor.set│"apoc.refactor.set│null   │null    │
│           │Type"             │Type(rel, 'NEW-TYP│Type(relationship │       │        │
│           │                  │E') change relatio│:: RELATIONSHIP?, │       │        │
│           │                  │nship-type"       │newType :: STRING?│       │        │
│           │                  │                  │) :: (input :: INT│       │        │
│           │                  │                  │EGER?, output :: R│       │        │
│           │                  │                  │ELATIONSHIP?, erro│       │        │
│           │                  │                  │r :: STRING?)"    │       │        │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

So, `apoc.refactor.setType` has these yieldable variables: `input`, `output` and `error`.

This query should work for you:

```
MATCH (user:Owner {email: "xyz@mymail.com"})-[r:OWNS]->(v:Vehicles {name:"Chevy"})
WHERE r.model = "Silverado" OR NOT EXISTS(r.model)
CALL apoc.refactor.setType(r, 'OWNED') YIELD output
RETURN user, output AS r, v
```

Comment: @cybersam....Thanks. I did see that in the docs but it wasn't clear.